# Expand the dataframe to fill missing MONTHYEAR and Bucket with other fields

Tags: pandas

A dataframe df1 exists like below

```
SALE_CTRY  BUILT_CITY CATEGORY MONTH_YEAR BUCKET RATE
 CA        Mumbai      rtyu     3/1/2004   3      5
 CA        Mumbai      rtyu     5/1/2004   4      6
 US        Mumbai      rtyu     8/1/2004   3      6
 IN        Delhi       aghaj    4/1/2005   5      4
 RU        Delhi       aghaj    8/1/2005   3      3
 RU        Delhi       aghaj    10/1/2005  2      5
```

Trying to add the missing BUCKET and as well as MONTH_YEAR
[image]

When I just had 4 columns like CATEGORY, MONTH_YEAR, BUCKET, RATE then I filled in like the below code

```
df1['MONTH_YEAR'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['MONTH_YEAR'])
rng = pd.date_range(df1[‘MONTH_YEAR’].min(),df1['MONTH_YEAR'].max(), freq='MS')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'MONTH_YEAR': rng})
df1['Bucket'] = df1['Bucket'].astype(int)
Bucket=np.arange(0,(df11['Bucket'].max()+2),1)
# repeating MONTH_YEAR as many times as bucket
df2=pd.concat([AVS2]*len(Bucket))
df2['Bucket']=np.repeat(Bucket, len(rng))
df3 = pd.merge(left=df2, right=df1, how='left',on=['MONTH_YEAR','Bucket']).fillna(0)
```

With other columns around how do I expand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `agg` and `merge`

```
cols = ['SALE_CTRY', 'BUILT_CITY', 'CATEGORY']
func = {'MONTH_YEAR': ['min', 'max'], 'BUCKET': ['max']}
aggs = df.groupby(cols).agg(func)

_df = pd.DataFrame([
    (s, b, c, m, bucket)
    for (s, b, c), mn, mx, bucket_mx in aggs.itertuples()
    for m in pd.date_range(mn, mx, freq='MS')
    for bucket in range(bucket_mx + 1)
], columns=[*cols, 'MONTH_YEAR', 'BUCKET'])

df.merge(_df, 'right').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

---

```
   SALE_CTRY BUILT_CITY CATEGORY MONTH_YEAR  BUCKET  RATE
0         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-03-01       0     0
1         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-03-01       1     0
2         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-03-01       2     0
3         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-03-01       3     5
4         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-03-01       4     0
5         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-04-01       0     0
6         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-04-01       1     0
7         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-04-01       2     0
8         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-04-01       3     0
9         CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-04-01       4     0
10        CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-05-01       0     0
11        CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-05-01       1     0
12        CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-05-01       2     0
13        CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-05-01       3     0
14        CA     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-05-01       4     6
15        IN      Delhi    aghaj 2005-04-01       0     0
16        IN      Delhi    aghaj 2005-04-01       1     0
17        IN      Delhi    aghaj 2005-04-01       2     0
18        IN      Delhi    aghaj 2005-04-01       3     0
19        IN      Delhi    aghaj 2005-04-01       4     0
20        IN      Delhi    aghaj 2005-04-01       5     4
21        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-08-01       0     0
22        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-08-01       1     0
23        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-08-01       2     0
24        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-08-01       3     3
25        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-09-01       0     0
26        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-09-01       1     0
27        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-09-01       2     0
28        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-09-01       3     0
29        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-10-01       0     0
30        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-10-01       1     0
31        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-10-01       2     5
32        RU      Delhi    aghaj 2005-10-01       3     0
33        US     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-08-01       0     0
34        US     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-08-01       1     0
35        US     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-08-01       2     0
36        US     Mumbai     rtyu 2004-08-01       3     6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract the process with the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to expose the missing rows, and fill with `fillna` - The rows will be exposed per groupby combination of `SALE_CTRY`, `BUILT_CITY` and `CATEGORY`:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
```

```py
# within the complete function the years and bucket will contain all rows,
# including the missing rows; fillna helps to replace the null values with 0.

expand = {'MONTH_YEAR': lambda year: pd.date_range(year.min(),
                                                   year.max(), 
                                                   freq='MS'), 
          'BUCKET': lambda bucket: range(bucket.max() + 1)}

(df.complete(expand, 
             by = ['SALE_CTRY', 'BUILT_CITY', 'CATEGORY'], 
             sort = True)
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)

   SALE_CTRY BUILT_CITY CATEGORY           MONTH_YEAR  BUCKET  RATE
0         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-03-01 00:00:00       0     0
1         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-03-01 00:00:00       1     0
2         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-03-01 00:00:00       2     0
3         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-03-01 00:00:00       3     5
4         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-03-01 00:00:00       4     0
5         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-04-01 00:00:00       0     0
6         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-04-01 00:00:00       1     0
7         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-04-01 00:00:00       2     0
8         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-04-01 00:00:00       3     0
9         CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-04-01 00:00:00       4     0
10        CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-05-01 00:00:00       0     0
11        CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-05-01 00:00:00       1     0
12        CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-05-01 00:00:00       2     0
13        CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-05-01 00:00:00       3     0
14        CA     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-05-01 00:00:00       4     6
15        IN      Delhi    aghaj  2005-04-01 00:00:00       0     0
16        IN      Delhi    aghaj  2005-04-01 00:00:00       1     0
17        IN      Delhi    aghaj  2005-04-01 00:00:00       2     0
18        IN      Delhi    aghaj  2005-04-01 00:00:00       3     0
19        IN      Delhi    aghaj  2005-04-01 00:00:00       4     0
20        IN      Delhi    aghaj  2005-04-01 00:00:00       5     4
21        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-08-01 00:00:00       0     0
22        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-08-01 00:00:00       1     0
23        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-08-01 00:00:00       2     0
24        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-08-01 00:00:00       3     3
25        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-09-01 00:00:00       0     0
26        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-09-01 00:00:00       1     0
27        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-09-01 00:00:00       2     0
28        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-09-01 00:00:00       3     0
29        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-10-01 00:00:00       0     0
30        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-10-01 00:00:00       1     0
31        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-10-01 00:00:00       2     5
32        RU      Delhi    aghaj  2005-10-01 00:00:00       3     0
33        US     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-08-01 00:00:00       0     0
34        US     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-08-01 00:00:00       1     0
35        US     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-08-01 00:00:00       2     0
36        US     Mumbai     rtyu  2004-08-01 00:00:00       3     6
```